# Does the mass of a rigid-body affect its bounce?

Tags: mass, computational-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm working on a computer program which involves some physics. I want to know if the mass of a perfectly rigid ball will affect how high it bounces off the ground. I'm in high school and I haven't studied physics just yet.

If the mass does affect bounce, please provide the governing equations. Thanks.

Comment: What is it bouncing off of?

Comment: In my case, the ground. I've added it to my question.

Comment: Is the ground also  perfectly rigid?

Comment: Yes, the ground is perfectly rigid.

Comment: A frictionless, perfectly rigid ball should conserve the energy when bouncing on a perfectly rigid ground. Therefore its mass doesn't play any role and the height of its bounces depends only on initial position and velocity.all.

Comment: Alright, my question has been answered. Thanks!